# Regarding simulating a family of distribution

Tags: r, simulation, lapply

I need to simulate the following distribution , by changing the value of the 'epso'. Where 'epso' is a sequence from 0 to 1 which is incremented by 0.1.

```
epso <- seq(0, 1, .1)
(1-epso)*replicate(n=2,rnorm(30,mean=0,sd=1)) + epso*replicate(n=2,rnorm(30,mean=0,sd=10))
```

i am trying to do this using an apply function. I thought the most suitable apply function for this is lapply. So this is my code.

```
lapply(epso=seq(0, 1, .1), function(epso) {
  (1-epso)*replicate(n=2,rnorm(30,mean=0,sd=1)) 
+ epso*replicate(n=2,rnorm(30,mean=0,sd=10)) }

)
```

But i am getting an error in this code. Can you help me to figure that out ?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameter that `lapply` iterates over is called `x=`. You cannot name it something else. (Typically the name is omitted completely). YOu should use

```
lapply(seq(0, 1, .1), function(epso) {
  (1-epso)*replicate(n=2,rnorm(30,mean=0,sd=1)) +  
    epso*replicate(n=2,rnorm(30,mean=0,sd=10)) }

)
```

By giving the parameter a name, your function was then the first unnamed parameter so it got promoted to the `x` value, and there was nothing left to be used as the `FUN` parameter.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. for some reason , the first sample generates  columns of zero.  Do you have any idea why is that ?

Comment: @Statlover Yes, there was a typo. I've fixed it. The plus sign needs to be at the end of the first line, not the start of the second.